# Reversing a string (input parameter and return a string)

Tags: c, string, reverse

I have to answer this question:

> Write a program which reverses the given string. (Input parameter and return string)

Does this question mean I have to take the input using command-line argument?
How will the return value work if I return a string to the main function?
Or is this just a misprinted question where I am supposed to make another function and return the value to some string in main function?

Answer (score 1):

The question means that you should implement a function that is a part of a program (probably a good idea to implement `main` to call/test the function). The function's' signature should be of the form:

```
char* reverse(char* str)
```

Although you could also implement (might be a little more difficult):

```
void inplace_reverse(char* str)
```

In my opinion, from the way the question is put there is no reason to believe you are to use command line arguments.

Comment: I think the word "program" is a very good reason to believe more than a function is needed.

Comment: I don't believe a downvote was required. And also I believe that yes, it is a *part* of a bigger program but the exercise is about this function.

Comment: You say *"From the question there is no reason to believe you are to use command line arguments."* I agree, but then why not: *"From the question there is no reason to believe you are to write a function other than main (which is only required because you are required to write a program)"*

Comment: I apologize if my terminology or the way I phrased myself isn't clear. You are welcome to edit my answer, but I really believe that the *sense* is clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this Question means i have to take input using Command line argument?

It doesn't specify, but I would as it makes the task easier.

> How will the return value work

Again, the question doesn't specify, so I would print it to the screen (`printf`).

> Or is this just a misprinted question where I am supposed to make another function and return value to some string in main function?

Calling a function from the main function would be a great idea and could only receive credit in my opinion although not explicitly specified.

One thing is clear, they ask for a **program** and not just a function, but both would be best in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

It means two things:

1- You must implement a function with the following signature:

```
char *reverse(const char *str);
```

2- You must implement a `main()` function which reverses the string passed as parameter:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *str;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string_to_reverse>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    str = reverse(argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neither "must" is implied by the question.